# Illustrator to chemdraw

Tags: software

I am not sure that this is the right place for this question, but I'll try.

I am working on a scheme that I am developing on illustrator. I have a lot of chemical structure and plus I have some vectorial pictures included.

The thing is that I would like to save/export my illustrator file in a way that I can reopen it and modify it in chemdraw. I am aware that the opposite procedure is possible.

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: I doubt that. Better keep your chemical part in ChemDraw and paste from it when ready.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a software issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From p. 327 of [ChemDraw 18 User Guide](https://chem.beloit.edu/classes/programs/ChemDraw_18_manual.pdf#page=337):

> #### Importing
>
> You can import graphics or documents from other applications into ChemDraw.
>
> **Files**
>   Files that you insert become part of the drawing. You can edit a file only if it is in a ChemDraw format.
>   To insert a file:
>
> 1. Navigate to **Edit → Insert File**.
> 2. In the Open dialog, select the file type from the drop-down list.
> 3. Select the file and click **Open**. The file is embedded in the drawing.

Further, there is a table of file formats ChemDraw is capable of importing and exporting, from which it is evident that only the following graphical formats can be *imported*:

- Bitmap (BMP)
- Graphic Image Format (GIF)
- JPEG (JPG, JPEG)
- Portable Network Graphics (PNG)
- Windows Metafile (EMF, WMF)
- Tagged Image File (TIF, TIFF)

PDF or PostScript files can be attached as objects, but I suppose it's not what you are after.
Either way, it looks like there is no way to add AI files directly, so you *need to convert them first* to either raster (e.g. TIFF or PNG) or vector (WMF) format.
I agree with @Ivan that crafting structures in ChemDraw in the first place and then post-processing them with Adobe Illustrator is arguably a better workflow.

Comment: Yes, we can export or import files in certain format from ChemDraw and to ChemDraw easily. But my understanding was, those files imported to ChemDraw cannot be changed except you can add more ChemDraw figures etc. because imported parts appears as a picture. For example, if you import a NMR spectrum, then you can add the structure and peak assignments, etc. bur cant change the appearence of spectrum. After add all you want, then you can save it in cdx or other formats in your answer. That's all I know. :-)